# UI for customized grouping

Tags: web-app

I'm building a lean CV (resume) management system (web-based) for HR people. Some users want to group CV by position, some like to group by skills, some like school, .etc, some even think of their quirky criteria.

Any suggested keywords for UI I should look up?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe tagging? Allowing different tags in order to filter CV's by anything HR people prefer.

[image]
[image]